# Create a new rule in existing AWS WAF rule group using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-waf

I am using waf v2. I have an existing rule group, let's call it TestRuleGroup. Inside this rule group I have one rule called TestRuleGroup-Rule1. Now I want to add a few new rules using aws cli. I know I should use update-rule-group but dont know how to use it.

I composed a json as below which includes the existing TestRuleGroup-Rule1 and a new TestRuleGroup-Rule2 that I am going to create. However, it seems adding this json to --cli-input-json is not the correct way. Anyone knows what I am supposed to do?

```
    "RuleGroup": {
        "Name": "TestRuleGroup",
        "Id": "9e22bd64-5f5f-46b5-8de3-xxxxxxxxx",
        "Capacity": 10,
        "ARN": "arn:aws:wafv2:ap-southeast-1:xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Description": "",
        "Rules": [
            {
                "Name": "TestRuleGroup-Rule1",
                "Priority": 0,
                "Statement": {
                    "ByteMatchStatement": {
                        "SearchString": "L2FiYy9kZWYvZ2hp",
                        "FieldToMatch": {
                            "UriPath": {}
                        },
                        "TextTransformations": [
                            {
                                "Priority": 0,
                                "Type": "NONE"
                            }
                        ],
                        "PositionalConstraint": "STARTS_WITH"
                    }
                },
                "Action": {
                    "Allow": {}
                },
                "VisibilityConfig": {
                    "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
                    "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
                    "MetricName": "TestRuleGroup-Rule1"
                }
            },
       {
                "Name": "TestRuleGroup-Rule2",
                "Priority": 0,
                "Statement": {
                    "ByteMatchStatement": {
                        "SearchString": "L2prbC9tbm8vcHFy",
                        "FieldToMatch": {
                            "UriPath": {}
                        },
                        "TextTransformations": [
                            {
                                "Priority": 0,
                                "Type": "NONE"
                            }
                        ],
                        "PositionalConstraint": "STARTS_WITH"
                    }
                },
                "Action": {
                    "Allow": {}
                },
                "VisibilityConfig": {
                    "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
                    "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
                    "MetricName": "TestRuleGroup-Rule2"
                }
            }
        ],
        "VisibilityConfig": {
            "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
            "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
            "MetricName": "TestRuleGroup"
        }
    },
    "LockToken": "8b9bd94d-56ed-4e17-ab55-xxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/wafv2/update-rule-group.html) help?

Comment: @TeddyAryono, thanks. I have read that article already, but not able to figure out how to make use of the update-rule-group command. Just wonder how --cli-input-json should be used.

Comment: You can do `--cli-input-json file://your-filename-here.json`